# how to add labels to Sections in XYZ piechart

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Hi i am using https://github.com/xyfeng/XYPieChart . When ever a section is selected i want to display relevant subject name in a label on that particular section. I am using two pie charts side  by side one displays the Target chart and other displays the Achieved chart. When ever user clicks a section in target's pie chart i have to display a label on that pie chart section and also on the Achieved chart section. How can i display label on that section.

Below are the methods which they have provided in that Framwork . (NSUInteger)index refers to the particular section or particular slice. How can i get the position on that index and display a label above it.

```
 -(void)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart willDeselectSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"will deselect slice at index %d",index);
    subjectLabelView.hidden=YES;
}


- (void)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart didDeselectSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"did deselect slice at index %d",index);
    subjectLabelView.hidden=YES;

}


- (void)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart didSelectSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

}
```

[image]